# UIActionSheet multiple selection possible iOS8 – does not remove UIWindow

Tags: uikit, ios8, uiactionsheet, uiwindow

I came across some weird iOS8 behavior and I don't know how to handle it. Seems like a bug to me. Perhaps you have a good idea for a workaround.

Way to reproduce: Create a UIActionSheet with at least two options. In iOS8 you have the chance to select multiple options at once. Just touch em: Works on device as well as simulator. This might also happen with bad aiming.

The delegate method

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

will be called twice. If it would stop here this would be easy: Just ignore the second delegate call. Problem though is that the _UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow is never dismissed, which leads to a UI block since our UIApplication's windows doesn't receive any touch events. If you run

```
po [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

in Debug mode you'll get the following output:

```
<_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow: 0x7bf5a3d0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7bf5af80>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7bf5a620>>
    | <UIView: 0x7bf5c460; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bf5c3f0>>
```

Also the delegate method

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

is never called.

Reseting the UIApplication's UIWindow with a dirty hack like:

```
[[(MyApplicationDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] makeKeyAndVisible];
```

doesn't work as well. Do you have any other ideas on how to fix this?

**To reproduce just put the following ViewController into a UINavigationController and you have the issue ... Just in case you don't believe me:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIActionSheetDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"ActionSheet" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonTouchUpInside:)];

    self.toolbarItems = @[buttonItem];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden: NO];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark Target Action

- (IBAction)buttonTouchUpInside:(id)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *aSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose an option" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Option 1", @"Option 2", @"Option 3", @"Option 4", nil];

    [aSheet showFromToolbar: self.navigationController.toolbar];
//    [aSheet showInView: self.view]; // doesn't make any difference
}

#pragma mark UIActionSheetDelegate

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Clicked at button index %lu", (unsigned long) buttonIndex);
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Did dismiss with button index %lu", (unsigned long) buttonIndex);
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Will dismiss with button index %lu", (unsigned long) buttonIndex);
}

@end
```

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, too. Here is a radar: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4786870772826112

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to solve this problem is to use `UIAlertController` in iOS 8 instead of `UIActionSheet`.

Here is example of how you can implement it in manner that will work fine with either iOS 8 or iOS 7:

```
- (IBAction)buttonCallingActionSheetPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    id alertControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIAlertController");

    if (alertControllerClass)
    {
        UIAlertAction *sheetAction = nil;
        UIAlertController *actionSheetController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                                       message:nil
                                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

        sheetAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Do something"
                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                            [self actionSheetSelectedIndex:0];
                                        }];
        [actionSheetController addAction:sheetAction];

        sheetAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                            [self actionSheetSelectedIndex:1];
                                        }];
        [actionSheetController addAction:sheetAction];

        [self presentViewController:actionSheetController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Do something", nil];
        [actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
    }
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self actionSheetSelectedIndex:buttonIndex];
}

- (void)actionSheetSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)selectedAction
{
    // Your logic goes here
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that the issue does not happen for me using UIAlertController.

Comment: Sebastian, are you running iOS 8.3+? I've found the use of UIAlertController still has the bug where you can multi tap multiple choices.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you described is not possible to occur, with this level of release from Apple. There might be some issue with delegate assigning or some thing like that. But, you can use this method to dismiss the ActionSheet in you delegate method (this is only a work around):

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Like this:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
     [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I just tried your solution and it doesn't work. Sorry. Seems to me like you haven't tried it yourself ... "The scenario you described is not possible to occur, with this level of release from Apple." In my defense I was quite shocked about such a bug as well. But it's in there. Try it ... Regards, fat

Comment: As i said earlier, you don't need this code.. its a work around. You should check your delegate assigning and your flow. I can't expect Apple to give this bug. But if you still say its from apple you should report it to Apple. Another suggestion is you should try your code in another project and then see what is happening there.

Comment: Since you don't believe me I added an example ViewController. Try it!

Comment: "A rectangle constant with location (0,0), and width and height of 0. The zero rectangle is equivalent to CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)."

Please edit your code and try to give a proper width/height in loadView function.. This might be causing your invalid touches, i.e., tapping on one/two button simultaneously. Actually i don't have 8.0 sdk installed yet. So, i'm just trying to help you debug your code. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed as of iOS 8.3+.